# Retrieve just a single result for each sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a chat application for my website. I've created the basic flow and I'm receiving and sending messages. But now I have to show all the chats of a user. The schema of my chat table is ID,Message,Sender,Receiver,IsRead. [!Here is the picture of schema.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDAue.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDAue.png) I've to get all the Distinct user, a particular user has sent message to. The query I've written so far is

```
SELECT DISTINCT FromUser 
FROM ChatMessages 
WHERE FromUser IN (SELECT DISTINCT FromUser FROM ChatMessages WHERE ToUser = @uid)
```

But this returns all the messages from the chat table of this user. Please help me if I need to write a different query. Or can I just retrieve a single row against each subquery that executes? Please note that I want to get the last message that a user has sent to another user with all the columns as well.
Thanks

Comment: `get the last message` ... which column in your table would enable us to figure out what is the last message?

Comment: with select top clause you can retrieve top records and you can combine it with order by clause to reach what you desired but, add a time field to your table may help more.

Comment: The Id  Column. The max ID for that result set I guess

Comment: please add some sample records

Comment: Add sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Answer (score 0):

use row_number() to assign a serial no per user and then just get one from each user

```
SELECT *, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FromUser ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
FROM   (
            SELECT * FROM ChatMessages 
       ) D
WHERE  D.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT  top 1 FromUser 
FROM ChatMessages 
WHERE 
ToUser = @uid and Datetime = (select max(DateTime) from ChatMessages where ToUser = @uid )
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
    CREATE TABLE ChatMessages 
        (id bigint  not null
        ,Message nvarchar(max)
        ,FromUser bigint not null
        ,ToUser bigint not null
        ,DateTime datetimeoffset(7) not null
        ,IsRead bit not null
        )

    INSERT ChatMessages
    VALUES (1,'MESSAGE', 100, 200, GETDATE()-1, 1)
        ,(2,'MESSAGE', 100, 200, GETDATE()-2, 1)
        ,(3,'MESSAGE', 100, 300, GETDATE()-2, 1)    
        ,(4,'MESSAGE', 400, 500, GETDATE()-3, 1)
        ,(5,'MESSAGE', 400, 500, GETDATE(), 1)
        ,(6,'MESSAGE', 100, 200, GETDATE(), 1);


    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx on chatMessages(FromUser, ToUser, Datetime DESC)
    GO
    CREATE FUNCTION fetchLastChat (@from bigint, @to bigint)
    RETURNS bigint
    AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN(SELECT TOP 1 id
                FROM ChatMessages
                WHERE FromUser = @from
                AND ToUser=@to
                ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
    END
    GO
```

My execution plan shows 100% clustered index seek...

ex:  SELECT dbo.fetchLastChat(100,200)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19bd8/1/0